# how do I get the number of seconds to 8am PST the next day?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how do I get the date time object of 8am PST the next day in javascript?

I tried new Date()

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you're not using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), i'd suggest doing so :)

Comment: "I tried new Date()" - well, `new Date()` obviously can't solve your problem. Your computer can't read your mind (yet), you have to tell it what you want to do... What did you try *to solve your problem*? Or didn't you try anything, and just hoped somebody else would write your code for you?

Comment: When you say "PST the next day", does it matter if, in locations operating under the PST timezone, the *"next day"* is in PDT? Also, *"next day"* relative to what time and in what timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Not very efficient, but here's a simple example.

```js
var today = new Date();
var diff = new Date(
  today.getFullYear(),
  today.getMonth(),
  today.getDate() + 1,
  8
).getTime() - today.getTime();

console.log((diff / 1000) | 0);
```

Comment: how do you set the timezone? Like, if I'm in Australia/Brisbane timezone, and want to know the number of seconds to 8am PST or PDT , how does this snippet figure that time difference ?

Comment: Nope, it figures everything in GMT. So it would figure your current time zone (it gets the current time in GMT and figures the difference to 8am GMT the following day). The Date documentation shows how to set a timezone offset.

Comment: I changed the code in order to improve performance and readability. Please make sure it still works like you expected. If it doesn't or if you're not pleased with the change, feel free to rollback the edit.

Answer (score -1):

Doing Date and Time manipulation is difficult with Node. **IF** you have PHP on your machine, I'd suggest this

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var command = 'php NumSecondsTo8am.php';
child_process.exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout, 'seconds');
});
```

Then, in a separate file in the same directory (I called *numSecondsTo8am.php*)

```
<?php
# numSecondsTo8am.php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

# get the current time
$currentTime = new DateTime();

# get the current time in Los Angeles, and add a day to it
$tomorrow = new DateTime();
$tomorrow->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

$dateInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$tomorrow->add($dateInterval);

# since we want to know about 8am, change the hour to 8am
$tomorrow->setTime(8, 0, 0);

# get the timestamp the future date will produce and subtract it from
# our current timestamp
$numSeconds = intval($tomorrow->format('U')) - 
    intval($currentTime->format('U'));

echo "$numSeconds";
```

Remember to change the timezone string to your local timezone! Otherwise, the answer won't be correct.

If you're looking for a pure Node solution, I haven't found one. 
Even using Moment won't give you the correct answer